# Deformed text in chrome

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs, html

We have a very weird behavior in our application, sorry I can't give examples but it's closed.

We see some extremely deformed texts, for example: [image]

Which SHOULD have been Edit Columns, but you can see what happens, when clicking inspect element, it shows everything is fine, and sometimes it fixes it self.

Few notes:

We are running a little bit old Ruby on Rails (1.9.3 Ruby, 3.2.17 Rails). 
The script is rendered by Angular but it sometimes happen in plain hamls as well (But more rarely).

It doesn't happen all the time.

It's possible it only happens on Chrome (since it's not persistent it's hard to make sure it really didn't happen).

Any ideas or suggestions or event hints will be extremely valuable, I am at a complete loss here.

Comment: Try adding this CSS -webkit-perspective: 1000;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased !important;

Comment: Is it per element that appears deformed or for the whole page? because it's not the only element.

Comment: Try adding it to the elements, it may not work anyway. I'm not to sure.